# GlobalAvgPool1D incompatible with output size

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pooling

My input shape is (150,10,1) and my output has the same shape (150,10,1). My problem is multi-classification (3 classes). After using np_utils.to_categorical(Ytrain) the output shape will be (150,10,3) which is perfect. However during the process of modelling with GlobalAvgPool1D(), it gives the error :
"A target array with shape (150, 10, 3) was passed for an output of shape (None, 3) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output". 
How should I fix it?

My codes:

```
nput_size = (150, 10, 1)
Xtrain = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(150, 10, 1))

Ytrain = np.random.choice([0,1, 2], size=(150, 10,1))
Ytrain = np_utils.to_categorical(Ytrain)

input_shape = (10, 1)
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape)
conv_x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=10, strides = 1, padding='same')(input_layer)

conv_x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv_x)
conv_x = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(conv_x)
g_pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool1D()(conv_x)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(g_pool)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs= input_layer, outputs = output_layer) 
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
          metrics='accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, batch_size= 5, epochs= 10, verbose= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code in Tensorflow Version `2.2.0` in Google colab, I got the following error - `ValueError: Shapes (5, 10, 3) and (5, 3) are incompatible`.

You are getting this error because, the labels `Ytrain` data is having the shape of `(150, 10, 3)` instead of `(150, 3)`.

As your labels are having shape of `(None,3)`, your input also should be same .i.e. `(Number of records, 3)`. I was able to run your code successfully after modifying,

```
Ytrain = np.random.choice([0,1, 2], size=(150, 10,1))
```

to

```
Ytrain = np.random.choice([0,1, 2], size=(150, 1))
```

`np_utils.to_categorical` adds the 3 columns for labels thus making the shape of `(150,3)` which our model expects.

**Fixed Code -**

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import utils as np_utils

Xtrain = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(150, 10, 1))

Ytrain = np.random.choice([0,1, 2], size=(150, 1))
Ytrain = np_utils.to_categorical(Ytrain)

print(Ytrain.shape)

input_shape = (10, 1)
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape)
conv_x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=10, strides = 1, padding='same')(input_layer)

conv_x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv_x)
conv_x = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(conv_x)
g_pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool1D()(conv_x)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(g_pool)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs= input_layer, outputs = output_layer) 
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
          metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, batch_size= 5, epochs= 10, verbose= 0)

print("Ran Successfully")
```

**Output -**

```
2.2.0
(150, 3)
Model: "model_13"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_21 (InputLayer)        [(None, 10, 1)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_9 (Conv1D)            (None, 10, 32)            352       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (Batc (None, 10, 32)            128       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)    (None, 10, 32)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d_9 ( (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 99        
=================================================================
Total params: 579
Trainable params: 515
Non-trainable params: 64
_________________________________________________________________
Ran Successfully
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Nazanin Fouladgar - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Thanks! What if my input_shape = (150, 10) and I consider every 2 rows for conv1D?  I mean I wanna  convolve  the "first two rows" of matrix (150,10) with a filter (2,10) and stride=1, "second two rows" with the same filter, "starting from second row of matrix till  third row of matrix"  and so on.

Comment: I modify "..till fourth* row of matrix and so on" , implying for considering previous time step with the current time step for convolution on a time series matrix.

Comment: Conv1D kernel_size must be an integer or tuple/list of a single integer, specifying the length of the 1D convolution window.

Comment: Assuming the kernel = 2, it will  slide over 10 features, right? If so, that is what I meant. However, gives error of "ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d_46 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 10 but received input with shape [None, 10, 1]"

Comment: I fixed the problem now by reshaping the Xtrain to (1, 150, 10), Ytrain to (1, 150, 1), input_shape (150, 10), kernel (2), without GlobalAvgPool1D. However, there is still error if this layer is added..